# Eclipse run configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, program-entry-point

When i'm trying to run in Eclipse program which has no main method as Java Application it always requires a main method to define. Could anybody please explain is there any simpler way to make configuration run without implementing

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Every program requires a main method.

The `public static void main(String args[])` starts the main thread which your program will run on.

There's more information available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/).

Answer (score 1):

You need a main method to run your program.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        YourClass newObject = new YourClass();
}
```

Put this method in your class (replace YourClass with your existing class) and hit the run button.

Answer (score 1):

> run in Eclipse program which has no main method

NO.You won't be able to run a class by using **IDE like Eclipse** or anything else. Even you won't be able to run your java program by using **Java command** from your command prompt, until your java program has  public static void main(String args[]) method on it. If you try to run, you will get below mentioned error

```
Error: Main method not found in class Test, please define the main
 method as:   public static void main(String[] args)
```

But you should also know that, **we can run a Java program without main method on managed environment** like the case of **Applet, Servlet and MIDlet**. There are actually different types of execution model available in Java, for example Applets which run on browser doesn't have main method. Servlet is also java program, which runs in a Servlet container and since Servlet is also a Java program, we can say that it runs without main method. Third one on this category is MIDlet, which runs on mobile devices.